# How to disclose complete information in GCP's operation logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I see that in GCP Logs (i.e., Operations Logging) that few key values are marked as `"[Filtered]"` (as in screenshot). 
Is it a security feature/setting to avoid disclosing too much information in logs, for eg., username etc. How can I disable this, basically I want to see all the information in logs unlike in screenshot. How can I do this please?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a log of which service? Are you seeing this directly in Cloud Logging? Do you know how the log are generated?

Comment: Google Cloud Data Loss Prevention will filter and prevent sensitive data in logs. More details on your environment is required.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Its logs coming from GKE pods/containers. And yes I am seeing this directly in GCP Logs (i.e., Operations Logging), basically I trying to dig logs from the past. Regarding how it is generated, it simply is forwarded via fluentd

Comment: @JohnHanley By more detailed I assume you are asking for the source of the log, its coming from our pods(ruby app) running on GKE.

Comment: I don't have clear the issue but I understood that the logs does not show you identifiable information (PII), if so, help me identify if you have the DLP enabled and proceed acordingly

Comment: by following the [document](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#api_overview), if this does not solve the issue, please give us more context regarding your inquiry

Comment: AFAIK, you can't plug DLP on Cloud Logging. But there is maybe a preprocessing into the pod to redact the PII before writing logs.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - Details are missing from this question. The company could be using Google DLP, a third party product, etc in their service/application. My comment was a suggestion to help the OP create a better question and know another place to look.